# How to display API data properly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, api

I am making a simple quiz web app in React and using an API to fetch questions. But when I display those questions on screen I get weird characters. How to resolve this issue?

I fetched the data as
`

```
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>setQuesArr(data.results))
```

`

I am displaying the question in this manner

`

```
<p>{JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.question))}</p>
```

`

Comment: what weird characters are you getting?

Comment: what is API result? can you give us the result?

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue; you haven't mentioned what you mean by 'weird characters'. How can we help if we don't know what characters you are talking about? We can only guess

Comment: I am getting characters like &quot;

Comment: @SiddhiNaik can you add the result you're getting as the response? at least a part of it? it will give a better understanding on what kind of characters you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the symbols such as `&quot;`? These are quotation marks, you can replace them before you put it into your paragraph tag, something along the lines of this:

```
var text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

This will replace all instances of your &quot with the " character (you can modify this for other tags that you come across as well)

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5")
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>setQuesArr(data))
```

You can try with this. just remove the **.results**